# OGraphDatabase ClassNotFoundException OrientDB 1.7.8

Tags: java, maven, orientdb

I have configured following pom.xml dependencies for OrientDB 1.7.8 in my project:

```
    <properties>
        <orientdb.version>1.7.8</orientdb.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- OrientDB bundles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orient-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-core</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-object</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-client</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.orientechnologies</groupId>
        <artifactId>orientdb-graphdb</artifactId>
        <version>${orientdb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

everything works fine with OrientGraph class, but I have ClassNotFoundException with OGraphDatabase.
How to add this class via OrientDB Maven dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OGraphDatabase has been deprecated ages ago. Stay with OrientGraph.